# Django receivers best practice

Tags: python, django, optimization, signals

I am deciding how I would like to write my receivers. I could do either of the following:

1. throw everything for one signal in one receiver
2. separate them intomultiple receivers for one signal for
   organizational purposes

my question is: **does it make a difference? If so, why?**

## Option 1:

```
@receiver(some_signal)
def do_it_all(sender, **kwargs):
    # do something for table 1
    # do something for table 2
    # do something for table 3
    #...
```

## Option 2:

```
@receiver(some_signal)
def do_it_for_one(sender, **kwargs):
    # do something for table 1
@receiver(some_signal)
def do_it_for_two(sender, **kwargs):
    # do something for table 2
@receiver(some_signal)
def do_it_for_three(sender, **kwargs):
    # do something for table 3
#...
```

Option 1 is clearly more **DRY**, but option 2 allows for more organization and **readability**, so they both have things going for them. But the real question is, **does it really matter?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end they'll both work. However, over time, you may find that `do_it_all` becomes quite big and you'll end up splitting it into multiple functions anyway:

```
@receiver(some_signal)
def do_it_all(sender, **kwargs):
    do_something_for_table_one(sender, **kwargs)
    do_something_for_table_two(sender, **kwargs)
    do_something_for_table_three(sender, **kwargs)
```

In that case it's not really different from option two.

So I'd argue that the second approach leads to cleaner code in the end. It also means you can test each receiver separately.

Comment: is there any processing time difference between option 1 and 2?

Comment: @RyanSaxe This question seems to answer that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10839834/1267329